# In html autostart option for audio control is not working in mozila firefox and chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser, mozilla

I embed the music in my website. it's working in IE but auto start is not working in Mozilla and chrome. please help to fix this issue. HTML:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="media/file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="media/file.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <embed height="50" width="100" src="media/file.mp3" autostart="true">
</audio>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `autoplay`: `<audio controls autoplay>`.

The `autostart` attrbiute does not exist in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#the-audio-element).

Comment: please, i have one more doubt.Music is stopped if may i turn to another link and starts from beginning. any option for the music is play continuously whether i go to another page like aboutus, products something like.

Comment: Once the page is unloaded, the music is gone. If this is a requirement, you could load content with ajax instead of having separate pages.